# Curve/Graph tracing

Tags: functions

Okay so I have to solve this question which requires me to find whether a function is one-one, onto, both, or neither.

The function is : $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{1+x^4}$.

I know I can solve this instantly without any fuss if I have its graph. The problem is, how can I mathematically draw its graph? That is, draw the graph with proper technique and logic, a method that would work for other similar problems as well.

Thanks for giving this your time!

Comment: Drawing the graph of this function is too much work. Instead ask yourself a different question: Is this function even, odd, or neither?

Answer (score 1):

Calculus is a wonderful tool for analyzing functions.  The derivative and second derivative of a function can be used to sketch its graph pretty accurately.  If you really want to know how to use math to graph functions, that's the answer.

But I don't think that's necessary for this problem.  The function is defined by a formula, so the one-to-one and onto questions can be answered by solving equations.

For instance, the question of whether $f$ is onto $\mathbb{R}$ amounts to asking: Does the equation
$$
    \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} = y
$$
have a solution $x$ for every real number $y$?  That equation is quadratic in $x^2$ so it can be solved definitively.

The question of whether $f$ is one-to-one amounts to asking: are there two different points of $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.  Notice this function is even; that's a big clue.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the following things

- check if it is an even or odd function
- domain
- intersection with axes
- discontinuity points
- sign of the function
- first derivative and its sign
- second derivative and its sign
- stationary points: flex points, local maxima and local minima
- asymptotic behaviour at the boundary of its domain

Comment: I do know pretty much the meaning of all these terms and their application , but I don't know just how to apply them and in what sequence in order to draw the graphs of functions .

Comment: If you know what that stuff is, you probably know as well their geometric meaning so you shouldn't have any problem to draw the graph once you checked all those things. By the way, notice that your function is continuous and behaves pretty much as $x^2$ at the origin and as $1/x^4$ at infinity. This should tell you pretty much all you need to know about its graph.